# Extract the nearest last month to date data if the same day of the last month did not have

Tags: python, pandas

How to extract the nearest last month to date data if the same day of the last month did not have the sale? Please refer to the sample provide for more understanding.

Original data:
[image]

It may not have the sale in the yesterday (last month), require to find the nearest day compare to today (last month).

Currently, using the `pd.merge` to get the `Last MTD` data, but if the same day of last month did not have the `product`'s sale, it will show `zero`.

Example 1:
02/10/2022 VS 02/09/2022
`02/10/2022` have `Clothes`'s sale, but `02/09/2022` did not have. Expect the `Last MTD` column able to display the `MTD` data from last month.

Current result:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Code:

```py
df["pdate"] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: (x - pd.DateOffset(months=1)))
df2 = df.copy()
final_df = pd.merge(left = df,right = df2, how="left", left_on=['pdate','Product'], right_on=['Date', 'Product'])
```

########   For understanding (can ignore)
###############
Example 2: 
03/10/2022 VS 03/09/2022
`03/10/2022` have `Dining room`'s sale, but `03/09/2022` did not have. Expect the `Last MTD` column able to display the `MTD` data from last month.

Current result:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) using a shifted period:

```
df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False).dt.to_period('M')

df['prev_period'] = df.groupby('product')['period'].shift()

out = (df.merge(df[['product', 'period', 'MTD']],
                how='left', suffixes=[None, '_previous'],
                left_on=['product', 'prev_period'],
                right_on=['product', 'period'])
         [['date', 'product', 'MTD', 'MTD_previous']]
      )
```

Example :

```
         date product  MTD  MTD_previous
0  01/09/2022       A    1           NaN
1  01/09/2022       B    2           NaN
2  02/09/2022       A    3           1.0
3  02/10/2022       B    4           2.0
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/09/2022', '01/09/2022', '02/09/2022', '02/10/2022'],
                   'product': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                   'MTD': [1, 2, 3, 4]
                  })
```